# How can I write test using mocha chai, for this function. I have been trying to do expect(notification(app).to.equal(url, messageBody)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, async-await, mocha.js, chai

```
const notification = async(app) => {
it does some for loop on app
await fetch (url, messageBody);
}

messageBody is an object
messageBody = {
method: 'POST',
body: {
name: 'User1',
text: 'hello'
},
headers: {
'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
};
```

I have been trying to do expect(notification(app).to.equal(url, messageBody). I am getting assertionError expected undefined to equal (url, messageBody).

Comment: So you should be returning something from notification function to test, if not you will have undefined and the error.

Comment: It just has a try block which await fetch and catch error. Is there any other way of testing it. These 2 are passing
expect(slack).to.be.a('promise');
expect(slack).to.be.an.instanceOf(Object);

Comment: You could use to.throw chai.expect(notification(app)).to.throw('The message...')